# Windows 10 Insider Preview Build has never updated

Tags: windows-10, azure, windows-insider

***Disclaimer: I know there are similar questions to this, but I have yet to find a solution/answer.***

I have a Windows 10 VM that I set up in Azure exactly 1 week ago. I am using my MSDN account since I get free money to spend in Azure (Yay me!). I signed up for Windows Insider preview on the same day.

I followed all steps to set up the machine to receive insider builds, and I changed my settings to "Fast", but I have still yet to receive any builds.System Information shows that I am still on Build 10586, which is what was installed when I set up the VM.

The Advanced Options under Update simply shows the following message:

[image]

Perhaps I am just being impatient, but what does "some time" mean? Is there a normal set amount of time before I should receive my first update?

I cannot find any documentation or answer anywhere. I feel like there may be some problem as to why I am not receiving a new build, but I do not know what.

Is there any way to check the status of when I will receive a build? Or is there any way to force it to update?

Please some more experienced Windows Insiders shed some light on this for me! Thanks!

Edit: Yes, I have tried manually checking for updates. I have done this multiple times, and it simply says that my device is up to date.

Comment: How long have you waited precisely?  The best way to upgrade to the Insider Preview is to mount the current Insider Preview .ISO.  [There are numerous reasons why the update would be blocked, far to many to list, which is the reason I suggest using the .ISO method.](http://superuser.com/questions/1064172/stuck-at-windows-10-build-1511-windows-update-doesnt-show-build-14316?noredirect=1#comment1497062_1064172)

Comment: [This](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10240-not-appearing-on-windows-update/) was published a year ago but it still applies today.  [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/why-am-i-not-receiving-the-latest-windows-10/ab019e58-753c-4a37-b24f-388793af068b?auth=1) highlights some restrictions to getting Insider Updates.  Be sure the Azure Active Domain one doesn't apply to you. These threads are old but they still apply today, if you recently upgraded the machine from 10240 to 10586 then your likely caught by a 30 day check.

Comment: I have waited 1 week. I will read the links you posted thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound I was really wanting to get build 14316, but it looks like that ISO isn't available yet. Perhaps I will just have just to be patient.... I was really just trying to find out if there was a specific time frame that I should expect to receive my first update build.

Comment: @Ramhound do you know if the 30 day check would apply for my VM since it was just provisioned? It wasn't upgraded to build 10586, that it what was installed when I set it up last week in Azure.

Comment: There are far to many restrictions to keep track of, so I don't bother, I have always used the .ISO method to perform these upgrades.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand. And I would have went the ISO route, but there is not an option for build 14316, even directly through my MSDN account. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: **So use the .ISO for the closest build, once you are on the RS_1 branch, the current build, will be offered.**  You must have not read all those links, because, I said the exact samething to somebody else.

Comment: My 14316 just showed up today maybe you just need to have patience

Comment: @Ramhound I read your links, I think I am best to wait until the .ISO is released for 14316, but I will try to do what you said.

Comment: @SeanClt Build 14316 actually was released on April 7th.  An .ISO won't be released until it hits the Slow Release RS_1 Branch.

Comment: @AlexChance - If I didn't know for a fact it would work I wouldn't be suggesting it.  Be sure you build a snapshot, so you can roll your virtual machine back, if you so desire.

Comment: Yep didn't use iso I was looking for this update since 8th but it showed up today only

Comment: Nope, it was released on the 7th, I got the link from an article post then...the current build has no ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add this for anyone in the future that may come across this post.

I followed the advice of @Ramhound and the links he provided in the comments and created a new VM in Azure from the downloaded image of Build 14295, which was the closest available ISO build. I followed all the steps to connect my MS account to the VM for insider preivew. I changed my insider preview settings to Fast track. I even used my MS account to sign into the VM.

I checked the registry settings as suggested by [this article](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10240-not-appearing-on-windows-update/) and ensured everything there was correct. Even after all this, I still did not receive the 14316 build.

I diligently checked my machine multiple times per day. I manually checked for updates. I restarted the machine several times. I changed my settings to developer mode. Even after following all these steps, I still did not receive the build.

Finally! Today, after a week of waiting, I logged into the VM, and the build was there. I do not believe any of this extra work I did helped....but I did learn some stuff from this, so it was not a complete waste of time. I think I would have received the build if I would have just left my VM as it was and kept waiting.

**tldr** - From my experience, I think the best advice is to just be patient and wait. If you have waited a significant amount of time (2 weeks), then maybe look into the other solutions.